# spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.1.RELEASE got UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.1.RELEASE in springmvc with spring verison 4.1.1 .And my elasticsearch server is up 5.5.0

After work with the example like:

```
@Repository public interface TestESearchRes extends 
ElasticsearchRepository<Test,Long>,ComService
```

When run the server I got:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'ESearchServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'testESearchRes'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
with name 'testESearchRes': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception 
is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

In ESearchServiceImpl:

```
@Autowired
private TestESearchRes testESearchRes;
```

But when I use spring-data-elasticsearch 1.3.0.RELEASE .It's ok.But can not connect to es

Can anyone help me.Thanks!

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @a.k Yes,I changed my spring version to 5.0.4.RELEASE  and spring-data-elasticsearch:3.0.8.RELEASE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

may be you can try up spring to 5.5.0,i have a problem like this,and up my spring version

Comment: Thanks a lot,even though there is no 5.5.0,but i changed spring to 5.0.4 this solved the proplem